# Get type name without any generics info

Tags: c#, .net, generics, reflection

If I write:

```
var type = typeof(List<string>);
Console.WriteLine(type.Name);
```

It will write:

> List`1

I want it to write just:

> List

How can I do that?
Is there a smarter way to do it without having to use `Substring` or similar string manipulation functions?

Comment: As of C# 6 you can do this with `nameof(List<string>)`

Answer (score 47, accepted):

No, it makes perfect sense for it to include the generic arity in the name - because it's part of what makes the name unique (along with assembly and namespace, of course).

Put it this way: [`System.Nullable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nullable.aspx) and [`System.Nullable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx) are very different types. It's not expected that you'd want to confuse the two... so if you *want* to lose information, you're going to have to work to do it. It's not very hard, of course, and can be put in a helper method:

```
public static string GetNameWithoutGenericArity(this Type t)
{
    string name = t.Name;
    int index = name.IndexOf('`');
    return index == -1 ? name : name.Substring(0, index);
}
```

Then:

```
var type = typeof(List<string>);
Console.WriteLine(type.GetNameWithoutGenericArity());
```

Comment: A practical use case is automatic conversion from a generic domain object, to a DTO, which usually doesn't support generics.

Comment: Here's the code from this answer [inside a static class and namespace for easier copy-and-pasting.

Also, there's another extension method to get the type its namespace.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70524352/569302)

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use regular expressions and give a replace?

`Regex.Replace(t.Name, @"\[.*\]", string.Empty);`

Comment: @RodrigoReis: "Better" how? I personally find the regular expression approach harder to read - it would take me longer to understand than the simple string operations. You may find the regex easier to read, of course - readability is subjective.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I agree, and it is a fact that string operations almost always outperform regular expressions, if programmed efficiently. But the more complex it gets, the harder it will be for string operations to keep up not only in performance issues, but also in maintenance issues.

Comment: @RodrigoReis: I didn't mention performance at all. For me this is *purely* about the readability of it, and I don't see that using a regex is more readable here. It doesn't seem to work, either - I tried changing the implementation to `return Regex.Replace(t.Name, @"\[.*\]", string.Empty);`, and then tested with the snippet at the bottom, and it printed `List'1` (with a backtick instead of an apostrophe) when the existing code prints `List` as expected. So again, in what way would the regex approach be better?

Comment: @JonSkeet Implementations are subjective when they do not present a deeper analysis, aren't they? Back to the subject of regular expressions, it is just a new way to implement a string parser, because compilers use this strategy in a certain way. Anyway, there is no right or wrong, just two truths, two ways.

Comment: @RodrigoReis: Well, there is "right or wrong" in terms of "the regex solution suggested appears not to do what was requested" unless I misunderstood how you expected it to be used. By that measure, I'd say my solution is objectively better. I still haven't seen why the regex solution (if corrected) would be better - not in general terms of string manipulation, but for *this specific functionality*. You originally suggested that regular expressions would be "better" so I'd still like to know in what way you'd expect them to be better (again, for *this* scenario).

Comment: @RodrigoReis: The implication was pretty clear that you thought it would be better - and why give a concrete example which then doesn't work? I suspect I *could* write a regex to solve the problem, but it would take me longer than the answer given, and wouldn't be as readable, at least for me. But if you're saying you were *really* just asking a perfectly innocent question of "Wouldn't it be better" then I can answer it easily: "No, I don't think a regex is a better solution for this problem".

Answer (score 2):

No, it doesn't, because the "generic-type-string" is part of the name of type.

Answer (score 2):

If someone is interested, I created some extensionmethods for this problem that create a more "readable" string

it produces something like

```
List[string]
outer.inner[other.whatever]
IEnumerable[T0]
Dictionary[string:int]
```

Test [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LxVGpZ)

```
public static class TypeEx
{
    public static string GetTypeName(this Type type)
    {
        if (type == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(type));

        if (!type.IsGenericType)
            return type.GetNestedTypeName();

        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        _buildClassNameRecursiv(type, stringBuilder);
        return stringBuilder.ToString();
    }

    private static void _buildClassNameRecursiv(Type type, StringBuilder classNameBuilder, int genericParameterIndex = 0)
    {
        if (type.IsGenericParameter)
            classNameBuilder.AppendFormat("T{0}", genericParameterIndex + 1);
        else if (type.IsGenericType)
        {
            classNameBuilder.Append(GetNestedTypeName(type) + "[");
            int subIndex = 0;
            foreach (Type genericTypeArgument in type.GetGenericArguments())
            {
                if (subIndex > 0)
                    classNameBuilder.Append(":");

                _buildClassNameRecursiv(genericTypeArgument, classNameBuilder, subIndex++);
            }
            classNameBuilder.Append("]");
        }
        else
            classNameBuilder.Append(type.GetNestedTypeName());
    }

    public static string GetNestedTypeName(this Type type)
    {
        if (type == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(type));
        if (!type.IsNested)
            return type.Name;

        StringBuilder nestedName = new StringBuilder();
        while(type != null)
        {
            if(nestedName.Length>0)
                nestedName.Insert(0,'.');

            nestedName.Insert(0, _getTypeName(type));

            type = type.DeclaringType;
        }
        return nestedName.ToString();
    }

    private static string _getTypeName(Type type)
    {
        return type.IsGenericType ? type.Name.Split('`')[0]: type.Name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6386234/569302) inside a static class and namespace for easier copy-and-pasting.

Also, there's another extension method to get the type its namespace.

```
using System;

namespace TODO
{
    public static class TypeExtensions
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6386234/569302
        /// </summary>
        public static string GetNameWithoutGenericArity(this Type t)
        {
            string name = t.Name;
            int index = name.IndexOf('`');
            return index == -1 ? name : name.Substring(0, index);
        }
        public static string GetFullNameWithoutGenericArity(this Type t)
        {
            var result = $"{t.Namespace}.{t.GetNameWithoutGenericArity()}";
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I can think of as of C#6(I think) you can do the following:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(nameof(List<int>));
    Console.WriteLine(nameof(Dictionary<int, int>));
}
```

This will print:

```
List
Dictionary
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    Console.WriteLine(WhatIsMyType<IEnumerable<string>>());
    Console.WriteLine(WhatIsMyType<List<int>>());
    Console.WriteLine(WhatIsMyType<IList<int>>());
    Console.WriteLine(WhatIsMyType<List<ContentBlob>>());
    Console.WriteLine(WhatIsMyType<int[]>());
    Console.WriteLine(WhatIsMyType<ContentBlob>());
    Console.WriteLine(WhatIsMyType<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, int>>>());
}

public static string WhatIsMyType<T>()
{
    return typeof(T).NameWithGenerics();
}

public static string NameWithGenerics(this Type type)
{
    if (type == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(type));

    if (type.IsArray)
        return $"{type.GetElementType()?.Name}[]";

    if (!type.IsGenericType) 
        return type.Name;

    var name = type.GetGenericTypeDefinition().Name;
    var index = name.IndexOf('`');
    var newName = index == -1 ? name : name.Substring(0, index);
        
    var list = type.GetGenericArguments().Select(NameWithGenerics).ToList();
    return $"{newName}<{string.Join(",", list)}>";
}
```

Example output:

```
IEnumerable<String>
List<Int32>
IList<Int32>
List<ContentBlob>
Int32[]
ContentBlob
Dictionary<String,Dictionary<Int32,Int32>>
```